# Calculation of 4 fields with another row

Tags: sql, oracle11g

Table1 has 6 columns that code, code1, %ofcode1, calc, code2, %ofcode2.

```
code code1 %ofcode1 calc code2 %ofcode2
 1    a      20      +     b      10
 2    1              -     c      
 3    2      10      *     d      10
```

Table2 has 2 columns that field, value.

```
field    value
  a        50
  b        20
  c        10
  d        20
```

I need final calculation value using function

calculation might be like tis using table1 format and getting values from table2.

```
   50*20/100 + 20*10/100        
     12      -  10               
   2*10/100  * 20*10/100    =  0.4
```

I need value that 0.4

Comment: Please format your question using code tags

Answer (score 0):

You can try implementing something along these lines.

```
DECLARE
    var_a VARCHAR2(50);
    int_a NUMBER;
BEGIN
    var_a := 'a'; -- SELECT code1 FROM Table1 WHERE code="input";

    IF REGEXP_LIKE(var_a, '^\d+(\.\d+)?$')
        THEN int_a := to_number(var_a, '9999.99');
        ELSE int_a := (-16);-- SELECT value FROM Table2 WHERE field=var_a
    END IF;

    dbms_output.put_line('first int is: ' || int_a);
END;
/
```